# NSURL not locating my video in my project

Tags: swift, nsurl

In my project, I have a video playing silently as a background video as an introduction. However, when I add the video to my project using `NSURL` I get this error (see screenshot). I have also provided the code below too. Any ideas?

```
let videoURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Background_2", withExtension: "mp4")!
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem myself. I would suggest using a video encoder (Adobe Media Encoder CC is good). In the media encoder change, the video codec to **H.264** and make sure it has a file extension of QuickTime **.mov** this will ensure Xcode and your application can read your video correctly.

In addition, when you have successfully changed the codec, make sure you add the video to your Bundle Resources!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Jordan i downloaded Adobe Media Encoded and edited my video, put it into xcode and it runs without a problem. Thanks for your help